# A list-based argument

Tags: pattern, story, knowledge

I have two asian friends who, like me, are into anime, comics and games. One is Chinese and one is Vietnamese.

One day, I found them both in front of a whiteboard, arguing intensively. They weren't speaking english, so I had no clue what they were saying.

My only clue was the board, where the following was written:

> 12
>   Remy - Pixar
>   Train Heartnet - Kentaro Yabuki
>   Sailor Moon - Naoko Takeuchi
>   Luffy - Eiichiro Oda
>   Orochimaru - Masashi Kishimoto
>   Hol Horse - Hirohiko Araki
>   Chi Chi - Akira Toriyama
>   Hobbes - Bill Watterson
>   Ryoga Hibiki - Rumiko Takahashi
>   Ryu - Capcom
>   Capricorn - Hiro Mashima
>   Arf - Akiyuki Shinbo
>   Foghorn Leghorn - Robert McKimson

I quickly realized that there are 13 characters here and not 12, which I supposed is what they are arguing about.

What are the criteria of the list, which characters are they arguing about, and why?

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough about the characters to know why they were arguing, but I know enough to recognize the probable relation to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_zodiac) if that helps anyone. I don't care to Google/read right now.

Comment: Your puzzles have been consistently good - they clearly have a lot of thought put into them! Keep it up!

Comment: This involved a lot of speed-Googling...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> They are arguing about which animal should be included based on the [Chinese](http://www.chinahighlights.com/travelguide/chinese-zodiac/) or [Vietnamese](http://vietnamesezodiac.com/) zodiacs.
>  - Cat versus Rabbit. Arguing between Train Heartnet and Sailor Moon.

Clues:

> 1. [Remy](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Remy) is a rat in the Pixar movie Ratatouille -> rat
>  2. [Train Heartnet](http://blackcat.wikia.com/wiki/Train_Heartnet) is a character in the series *Black Cat*. -> cat
>  3. [Sailor Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailor_Moon). The main character Usagi has a name that means "rabbit" -> rabbit
>  4. [Luffy](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Monkey_D._Luffy) (full name Monkey D. Luffy) is the main character in One Piece, a Manga by Eiichiro Oda -> monkey
>  5. [Orochimaru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orochimaru_(Naruto)) is a villian in the manga Naruto by Masashi Kishimoto and is known for his use of snakes as weapons (jutsus) as well as being overall personified as a snake -> snakes
>  6. [Hol Horse](http://jojo.wikia.com/wiki/Hol_Horse) is a villain in the manga JoJo's Bizarre Adventure Part 3 by Hirohiko Araki-> horse
>  7. [Chi-Chi](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Chi-Chi) is main character in the Dragon Ball series (the wife of Goku) by Akira Toriyama. She is the Ox-Princess -> ox
>  8. [Hobbes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvin_and_Hobbes) is a tiger and a main character in the comic strip *Calvin and Hobbes* -> tiger
>  9. [Ryoga Hibiki](http://ranma.wikia.com/wiki/Ryoga_Hibiki) is the main rival of the main character in *Ranma ½*, and is also known as Pig Boy. He turns into a piglet, -> pig
>  10. [Ryu](http://capcom.wikia.com/wiki/Ryu) is a fighter in the Capcom game Street Fighter. One of his moves is Dragon Punch. His very name can mean "dragon" -> dragon
>  11. [Capricorn](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Capricorn) is a member of the zodiac with the appearance of a goat. -> goat
>  12. [Arf](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Alph) is the familar of Fate, and in her previous animal life was a puppy in a wolf pack. She turns into a small dog when wounded. -> wolf/puppy
>  13. [Foghorn Leghorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foghorn_Leghorn) is a rooster in the Looney Toons cartoons. -> rooster

Comment: I added some more information to your answer (still working on the rest) so people not knowledgeable in manga, comics, etc.. can still understand the answer

Comment: You're on the right path, but your answer's not complete yet. Please note also that I said which characters (plural).

Comment: @GordonAllocman I'm working on it, don't bother. It just interrupts or conflicts my editing.

Comment: @mbomb007 my apologies, I wanted to edit your answer rather than post my own so I wouldn't steal any credit

Comment: @Will Be patient. I'm in the process of editing. And yes, ty. I'd fixed that, but a conflicting edit by Gordon removed it when I merged.

Comment: The missing part is probably related to the differences between the Chinese and Vietnamese zodiacs.

Comment: In the Vietnamese zodiac, a water buffalo replaces an ox. Those are the two that they're arguing about.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. What zodiac is for Harvest Moon?

Comment: @mbomb007 about Capricorn, he is literally one of the zodiacs in the show Fairy Tail, used by Lucy Heartfilia, except that Fairy Tail is written by Hiro Mashima, not Jenzu Wong

Comment: @mbomb007: Her name, "usagi", means "rabbit".

Comment: And a cat replaces the rabbit in the Vietnamese zodiac.

Comment: I also had Ryoga as dog, but he should be pig. I fixed that.

Comment: @Gordon I'll correct that. I have no clue how I made that mistake.

Comment: @Seraviel That explains why it was so hard for me to find!

Comment: @Gordon Search Jenzu Wong on google, and you'll find how I made that mistake. (Answer: Bad Wikipedia edit by someone)

Comment: @mbomb007 You still have a mistake there. I will point out that the Chinese zodiac character for Ox includes Buffalo. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ox_in_Chinese_mythology)

Comment: @Seraviel Okay, so they agree on that, then.

Comment: @mbomb007 You still have an error in 10 & 11.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39247/discussion-between-mbomb007-and-seraviel).